# CS0016: Could not write to output file - 'The directory name is invalid. '

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, visual-studio, iis

I get the following error on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 and cannot figure out how to fix it. The project compiles fine in Visual Studio and can run in IIS Express but fails with the error below when run in the browser under IIS.

I have tried the following:

- Repair visual studio
- Reinstall IIS
- Given full permissions to folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ for users like IUSR, Network Service, App pool identity, Everyone and more.
- Restart computer
- Checked TEMP and TMP environment system variables
- And a lot more settings in Visual Studio and IIS.

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fd2a209\ed3ad2ce\App_global.asax.-2hhmbh2.dll' -- 'The directory name is invalid. '
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.0079.0
>
> for C# 5
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
>
> error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1fd2a209\ed3ad2ce\App_global.asax.-2hhmbh2.dll' -- 'The directory name is invalid. '

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio "As Administrator"?

Comment: Is I am running as administrator